# The fbx file can't load in ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net-core, three.js

I use three.js in my project. In developing front-end everything was OK, but after copy/past code in .cshtml files and migrate static files in wwwroot, a JavaScript file contatins threejs loader cannot load .fbx file. After run project give 404 error.

This code get .fbx file.

```
let loader = new FBXLoader();
loader.load("/fbx/earthfbx2.fbx", function (object) {
    //do somethings
});
```

Comment: Whether the "fbx" folder is in the wwwroot folder or not? Can you capture a screenshot about the wwwroot folder directory?

Comment: the directory is true. in somewhere says I must include .fbx MIME type. but i don't know how to do it. if your have solution please help me.

Answer (score 1):

after some search, I improve problem by adding this lines of code in startup.cs `Configure` method

```
 var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        // Add new mappings
        provider.Mappings[".fbx"] = "application/octet-stream";
        provider.Mappings[".myapp"] = "application/x-msdownload";

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot")),
            ContentTypeProvider = provider
        });
```